# Redeclaration of "let MyClass" when defining an "enum" using an Object inside a JS class without class instantiation (no let is used)

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to define an "enum" using an Object and freeze inside a `JS` class in the next manner:

```
//test.js
class MyClass{
    static MyEnum = Object.freeze({
        kZero: 0,
        kOne: 1
    });
}

console.log(MyClass.MyEnum.kZero);
console.log(MyClass.MyEnum.kOne);
```

When running the `html` file in `firefox` I get the next output:

```
0                                          test.js:8:9
1                                          test.js:9:9
Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let MyClass
    <anonymous> file:<path>/test.js:1
```

Can someone please explain what's wrong or direct me to a source where it's explained? I read the related posts, but all I could find are cases when `let` is indeed used.

The `html` file:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="test.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_styles.css"></link>    
    <title>Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the `css` file it empty.

Comment: I see `<script src="test.js"` x 2 ...

Comment: You're trying to load your script twice (once in `head` and once in `body`), which means that you're trying to declare `MyClass` at global scope twice, which you aren't allowed to do. The error message isn't ideal, but `let`, `const`, and `class` all create the same kind of binding (a "lexical binding"), which is sometimes colloquially called a "let" declaration; unlike "var" bindings created by `var` and `function`, you can't redeclare them. To fix it, just remove one of the two `script` tags.

Comment: Re your edit: That fixes the problem. If you're still seeing it, I suggest you haven't saved the file or similar. I've copied your HTML and JavaScript locally and run it in Firefox, without the error. (Whereas with your original HTML trying to run the script twice, I get exactly the error you've quoted.)

Comment: `but it still does not work` if it's the same error, you are probably using Chrome or a Chromium based browser that hangs on to cached files like a 1950's unwed mother to a child

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. You are right I opened the wrong version of the file. Re-edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have the script tag for "test.js" included twice, once in the head and once in the body of your HTML file. This is causing the script to be loaded and executed twice, which results in the error you're seeing.

#### Here's the corrected HTML file:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="test.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_styles.css"></link>    
    <title>Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Remove the following line -->
    <!-- <script src="test.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

**By removing the extra script tag in the body, you should only load "test.js" once, and the redeclaration error should be resolved. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing the updated HTML file.**